# How do I display associated list data alongside workflow task form?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath

In my workflow task form, I wish to provide the user the associated list details (such as Title, Description, and Date Needed) alongside the fields I am collecting (Approval, Budget). I am using Sharepoint Server 2010, Designer 2010, and InfoPath 2010. When I "collect data from a user" in my Designer workflow, an InfoPath form is created for the user to fill out. In 2007 I was able to edit the custom .aspx task form with my desired fields, but I am at a loss as to how to do the same using this new InfoPath form method.

Can I use these fields in InfoPath? Can I edit the form outside of InfoPath?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this in the past by copying the required fields to the task item when it's created. This has the drawback that you can't edit them and show the changes in the parent item and they are not updated when they change in the parent item.